# How to match character instead of using backslash in PERL

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, match

Assume that my string is `"sample text &#x2013; and so on.."`

in perl we have use backslash while matching in some cases like : `sample text \&\#x2013\; and so on..`

I want to know is there any other way to match any string instead of using backslashes while matching?

Comment: `perldoc -f quotemeta`

Comment: Please give an example to show what it is you want to do. Are you writing a regex pattern to match a particular string? Note that none of the characters in the string you show need escaping. `/&#x2013;/` is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you want to use a literal string for comparison inside a regular expression, just use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) on it.

There are also some helpful escape codes to shortcut that process, `\Q` ... `\E`, which can be included inside a double quoted string or regex LHS to escape special characters.